# How to create a user while logged in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, sublimetext

I want to create another account while logged in to an account. I didn't edit anything because I have no clue on what to edit.

Please Help. Thank you.

Here's my RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
}
```

and this is the auth route in router.php

```
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    $this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
}
```

Comment: which version of laravel you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new Controller.

> UserController.php

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
   return User::create([
     'name' => $request->name,
     'email' => $request->email,
     'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
   ]);

return //whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Laravel 5.4

you can add this in your Auth/RegisterController

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

that would require the user to be logged before register ..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom controller if you want to and not modifying the 'RegisterController' and here's how to do it.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

//use Auth
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // check if user is logged in, if not then redirect them to the login page
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function registerUser(Request $request){
        // assume data validation here

        //save user to database
        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
        $user->save();

        return //return whatever
    }

}
```